# Error consulta sql usando php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
<tr id="campo-select">
        <td>    
            <strong>Personas:</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php $consulta_listar_usuario = $usuario->listUserpordepartamento($conexion); ?>
            <span id="error-persona">
                <select class="browser-default" name="persona0" id="persona0" required>
                    <option value="0">-</option>
                    <?php while($resultado_listar_usuario = $consulta_listar_usuario->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>
                                  <option value="<?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['idUsuario'];?>"><?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['personaNombre'];?> <?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['apellido'];?>   <?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['email'];?> <?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['nombreDepartamento'];?></option>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                 </select>
            </span>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn" id="suma_persona" ><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn" id="borra_persona" ><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="cantidad_persona" id="cantidad_persona">
        </td>

    </tr>
```

tengo un elemento en una tabla el cual me trae con una consulta sql los valores de los usuarios registrados.

Estoy tratando de hacer un filtro que me traiga solo los campos que contengan un id especifico , como el que usa el usuario ingresado

```
function listUserpordepartamento($conexion){

        $consulta = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, p.id as idPersona, d.nombre as nombreDepartamento, u.id as idUsuario, u.nombre as nombreUsuario
                                              FROM persona as p
                                              JOIN usuario as u
                                              on p.id = u.id_persona
                                              JOIN departamento as d
                                              on u.id_departamento = d.id
                                              ORDER BY p.nombre ASC")) or die("Error listando Usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }
```

tengo errores al traer los campos  , declaro la variable de forma privada

```
private $departamento;
```

y el departamento

```
function setDepartamento($departamento){

        $this->departamento = $departamento;
    }
```

espero se entienda, yo ya me enrede .
gracias por la ayuda

Comment: En donde hace la llamada de la función `listUserForDepartament` ?

Comment: perdona , no la habia puesto en el codigo. ya lo hice pero sin exito , lo que quiero es saber como modificar el while que esta en mi html del comienzo para que me traiga los datos si el id del departamento es el mismo .

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta , me complique muchisimo @Dev.Joel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$id_departamento = $resultado_usuario['id_departamento'] ;
```

no habia declarado en ningun momento el id_departamento de la persona que ingresaba al sistema

luego

```
<tr id="campo-select">
        <td>    
            <strong>Personas:</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php $consulta_listar_usuario = $usuario->listUserpordepartamentodos($conexion, $id_departamento ); ?>
            <span id="error-persona">
                <select class="browser-default" name="persona0" id="persona0" required>
                    <option value="0">SELECCIONE A QUIEN NOTIFICAR</option>
                    <?php while($resultado_listar_usuario = $consulta_listar_usuario->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['idUsuario'];?>"><?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['personaNombre'];?> <?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['apellido'];?>   <?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['email'];?> <?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['nombreDepartamento'];?></option>





                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                 </select>
            </span>
```

lo que hice fue asignar los nombres y colocarlos en mi metodo

a la final modifique un poco mi fuction como me recomendo @Eduardo Javier Maldonado gracias (y)

```
function listUserpordepartamentodos($conexion, $id_departamento){

        $consulta = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, p.id as idPersona, d.nombre as nombreDepartamento, u.id as idUsuario, u.nombre as nombreUsuario
                                              FROM persona as p
                                              JOIN usuario as u
                                              on p.id = u.id_persona
                                              JOIN departamento as d
                                              on u.id_departamento = d.id
                                               WHERE  u.id_departamento = ".$id_departamento)) or die("Error listando Usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo el porque cambiar de respuesta correcta, si básicamente conteste a la pregunta que realizaste aqui en Stackoverflow la cual era un error en tu consulta SQL no de HTML o cualquier otro lenguaje.

Answer (score 1):

Al ver como tienes tu función y tus tablas queda de la siguiente forma:

```
function listUserForDepartament($conexion, $departamento){
    $consulta = (
        mysqli_query($conexion, 
        "SELECT p.nombre AS personaNombre, p.id AS idPersona, d.nombre AS nombreDepartamento, u.nombre AS nombreUsuario
            FROM persona AS p
            JOIN usuario AS u ON p.id = u.id_persona
            JOIN departamento AS d ON u.id_departamento = d.id
            WHERE d.id = ".$departamento.""))
            or die("Error listando usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    return $consulta;
}
```

Si estas trayendo el `id` del `departamento` bien, no debería de causarte ningún inconveniente.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: departamento in C:\xampp\htdocs\helpdesk\sistemas\helpdesk\partes\respuestaTicket.php on line 42
Error listando usuarios: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5 @eduardo Javier

Comment: tenia un punto de mas antes del mysqli_error tambien .

Comment: Mi pregunta es en la clausula where, tu con que tabla estas comparando? , yo en este caso tome tu tabla departamento para hacer dicha comparación, mas no se en cual te bases tu, si en la tabla departamento o en usuario.

Comment: a la de usuario tiene un id_departamento, y la tabla departamento tiene un id que podria tambien usar . quiero usar la del departamento .

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta para mostrar otra funcion que uso para mostrar los usuarios de los departamentos .

Comment: como puedo saber si me estoy trayendo el id del departamento? 
puedes aclararme eso ? 
soy muy nuevo y apenas estoy haciendo funcionar esto

Comment: Puedes utilizar un die(var_dump($variable)); cuando escribas eso morirá todo el proceso y imprimira lo que contiene la variable. o también puedes poner el puro var_dump() pero el proceso continuara.

Comment: gracias @eduardo pero ya solucione

Comment: De nada, la respuesta que te sirvio puedes marcarla como buena, ya que solo se te respondio tu pregunta acorde a lo que tu mostraste. Saludos!